# A big amount of requests to one site python

Tags: python, sockets, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Well i am learning now how do requests works what are the limits, and i got a problem with something, i am using Python(PyCharm) 3.4 , with the libraries of urllib.request BeautifulSoup,
now i have a site that i am runnning test on him,
i have this function:

```
def GetAll(url):
   req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
   html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
   header = soup.find('h1', attrs={'sub': re.compile("subheader")}).string
   return header
```

Its just a simple function that i am sending a bunch of pages(urls) and i do a `

```
while untill an index <= len(pages):
   header = GetAll(pages[index])
   print(header)
```

so some forums got 10~20 pages , and some got 100~300 pages and 50 subjects per page,
but at the end of the day i back to see if the list is done to print
and sometimes its prints 100 headers sometimes 1000 and sometimes up to 5000 i need it to print all of it after a little math 30K subject, so ineed to do 30K requests but i end up with this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1183, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 871, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 537, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Well what does `errno 11004` mean?

Comment: @RedX i Don't know that what i am asking lol

Comment: According to the [Windows Sockets Error Codes (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) table it seems to be a DNS problem.

Comment: @DAdams , i am getting the same error

Comment: @BlackJack What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Does your request get the page source for a single URL cleanly?

Comment: What do you mean by cleanly , my code is sending a request to each page and i get tons of subjects just as you see up there in the code,
after 500 request to this specific site its show me this error , and i am just rolling over all of the pages on a specific subject.

Comment: It's either a problem with your network, then hunt that down and fix it. Or it's a problem outside your network/reach.  It may even be a counter measure from a site you are hammering with tons of requests. Then throttle the request rate. In any case you should expect and handle such errors somehow. At least by remembering/logging the failed requests and maybe try again later.

Comment: @BlackJack the problem i don't know from which line its comes from , i can't try and except it, check the error i can't see from where it comes

Comment: The line should be in the traceback.  And looking at your traceback it does not seem to be complete!